# VB.NET How do I pass parameters to a class?

Tags: vb.net

Relatively new to coding and have taken up lots of small projects to help learn the basics, and I have now set myself a challenge of a "bigger" one. Essentially I want to recreate the Message Box but with my own styling and customisable elements.

I have got the basics in a class and created it, however I want the class to have two options.

1) load all the details from an XML file for the message, I have done this and that works.

2) I want it to be like the standard message box where you can pass in parameters.

My question is, How can I achieve number 2.

I have tried adding details into the Show/Load subs but no luck, the only way around it I can see is with properties but that would take too long.

I want to be something like the below.

```
classname.show("message","tittle",icon,"buttons",imagefile,"caption")
```

However alot of my code is done in the load method as opposed to show, so it needs to be visible / accessible there.

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How is it that you can't simply create an overload of the Show method with the parameters you wish to have.  I'm confused as to why that would be a problem

Comment: I don't quite think I have reached that level of skill yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are definitely the way to go. It also makes sense: Conceptually, the message being shown *is* a property of the message box.

Your `Show` method would look like this:

```
Public Shared Show(message As String, title As String, ...)
    Dim box as New MyMessageBoxWindow()
    box.Message = message
    box.Title = title
    ...
    box.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

In the `Load` method of `MyMessageBoxWindow`, you access these properties and configure the UI elements.